# Is it an object or array?

Tags: javascript

I cannot understand the following code, `var formData = {};` I guess defines a object "formData", but why to save each element in the `formdata["fullName"]`? What is this with []? Isn't it used for array? i confused. Could somebody explain this code? Thank you!

```
function readFormData(){
    var formData = {}; 
    formdata["fullName"] = document.getElementById("fullName").value;
    formdata["empID"] = document.getElementById("empID").value;
    formdata["salary"] = document.getElementById("salary").value;
    formdata["city"] = document.getElementById("city").value;
    return formData;
}
```

Comment: It's one of access methods. Same as `formData.fullName`. Consistency maybe? You can use `[]` or `.` for accessing object properties

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Accessing_properties

Comment: `[]` is a property access called bracket notation. Its used when we need to access properties dynamically. By the way arrays in javascript are also objects.

Comment: Also, there a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) constructor which takes the form element as a parameter and creates a key-value pair of all the inputs in the form. `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("yourFormId"))`

Comment: @LGSon oh, right I did not consider that, apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In javascript, array keys are defined and referenced with square brackets. Object properties can be defined an accessed the same way or with dot notation.

In your case you do have an object, and it's properties can be accessed using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

The following two lines are thus equal:

```
  obj["property"] = value;
  obj.property = value;
```